# How to add multiple imageview on in a layout in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am making an android application in which I need 9 imageviews in a single layout. But When I try to do that, I get:- '`Unfortunately, "AppName" has stopped`'  error.
I don't know why this is happening. Am I doing something wrong? This error only comes when I add more than 1 imageview.

**Here is my code**

```
package com.yimcooldude.findtheball;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.os.Build;

public class GameActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    ImageView ball1,ball2,ball3,ball4,ball5,ball6,ball7,ball8,ball9;
    RelativeLayout rel;
    int x, y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_middle, R.anim.to_middle);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


        rel=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel2);



        ball1 = new ImageView(this);
        ball1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        rel.addView(ball1);

        ball2 = new ImageView(this);
        ball2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher2);
        rel.addView(ball2);

        ball3 = new ImageView(this);
        ball3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher3);
        rel.addView(ball3);

        ball4 = new ImageView(this);
        ball4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher4);
        rel.addView(ball4);

        ball5 = new ImageView(this);
        ball5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher5);
        rel.addView(ball5);

        ball6 = new ImageView(this);
        ball6.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher6);
        rel.addView(ball6);

        ball7 = new ImageView(this);
        ball7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher7);
        rel.addView(ball7);

        ball8 = new ImageView(this);
        ball8.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher8);
        rel.addView(ball9);

        ball9 = new ImageView(this);
        ball9.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher9);
        rel.addView(ball9);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        }
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
       super.onResume();       
       rel.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
       {
           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
           public void onGlobalLayout()
           {
               // gets called after layout has been done but before display.
               rel.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);


               x=(rel.getWidth()/2)-18;
               y=(rel.getHeight()/2)-18;
               TranslateAnimation animSurprise2Movement = new TranslateAnimation(0,x,0,y);
            animSurprise2Movement.setDuration(10000);
            animSurprise2Movement.setFillAfter(true);
            animSurprise2Movement.setFillEnabled(true);

           ball1.startAnimation(animSurprise2Movement);

           // get width and height
           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_game.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.yimcooldude.findtheball.GameActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
08-25 04:05:29.210: D/dalvikvm(898): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-25 04:05:32.490: D/(898): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7af1e98, tid 898
08-25 04:05:32.910: W/EGL_emulation(898): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-25 04:05:32.930: D/OpenGLRenderer(898): Enabling debug mode 0
08-25 04:05:37.630: D/AndroidRuntime(898): Shutting down VM
08-25 04:05:37.630: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4af2ba8)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Process: com.yimcooldude.findtheball, PID: 898
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yimcooldude.findtheball/com.yimcooldude.findtheball.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3353)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.yimcooldude.findtheball.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:76)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-25 04:05:37.710: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 11 more
08-25 04:05:56.010: I/Process(898): Sending signal. PID: 898 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this :

```
        ball8 = new ImageView(this);
        ball8.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher8);
        rel.addView(ball9);
```

to

```
        ball8 = new ImageView(this);
        ball8.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher8);
        rel.addView(ball8);
```

Comment: I don't know how I did that mistake but yoy were a life savior.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code:

```
        ball8 = new ImageView(this);
        ball8.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher8);
        rel.addView(ball9);
```

Via

```
    ball8 = new ImageView(this);
    ball8.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher8);
    rel.addView(ball8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with basic way

```
_ delete rel=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel2);  ( I dont know what it did ? )
_ ball1 = (ImageView) findViewby(R.id.idOfImageview)
```

the same with Imageview remaining..

**Remember create imageview in layout.** , and sort all imageview in layout file.